# Sonar with Maven: Fail to connect to database: Cannot loa d JDBC driver class 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'

Tags: maven, sonarqube

Objective: Get Maven to publish sonar results to running Sonar server

Steps:

- Installed and ran Sonar, accessible from browser

  - The back-end database is Oracle
- Installed and configured Maven in settings.xml file to connect to the Oracle db
- Invoked: mvn clean install -DSkipTests=true
- Invoke: mvn sonar:sonar

But getting following mvn sonar:sonar
Fail to connect to database: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'

So I need somehow to put the ojdbc6.jar on Maven classpath. Tried placing the ojdbc6.jar in /lib and lib/ext but did not help.

Am I missing something here? please help.

Answer (score -1):

To fix this I modified *maven113home/bin/mvn*.bat at line 161 and added

```
%MAVEN_JAVA_EXE% %MAVEN_OPTS% -classpath path/to/ojdbc6.jar;...
```

**Which is nasty!**

Please suggest a better approach.

Comment: Did you place the ojdcbc6.jar into SONARQUBE_HOME/extensions/jdbc-driver/oracle ?

Comment: Yes already did that and it works fine. The problem I'm having is on the Maven side when invoke mvn sonar:sonar, Maven is not picking up the driver from maven/lib or maven/lib/ext. Thanks